# pull 'authorization' token from python http request

Tags: python-requests

I'm not sure how to pull the bearer token from the responce. Hints?
[image]

auth = response.headers..... ?

Comment: Is that authorization exposed?

Answer (score 0):

it's not as sexy as I would like it, but it works:

```
import requests
import json

def arraySearch(array_search, search):
    r = None
    if len(array_search) > 0:
        for a in array_search:
            if a[0] == search:
                r = a[1]
                break

    return r

url = "http://10.1.1.100:80/authorization/login"

payload = json.dumps({
    "username": "2",
    "password": "2"
})
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

headerObj = response.headers.items()
auth = arraySearch(headerObj, "authorization")

print(auth)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).